# VBA, how to check if file exists fast (file on network)

Tags: vba, winapi

I am trying to check if a file exists on a network. but sometimes the network is not connected
and the application is freezing.

```
Private Function FileExistsSlow(ByVal path_ As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    FileExists = False
    FileExists = (Len(Dir(path_)) > 0)
End Function
```

Comment: [Superstition: Why is GetFileAttributes the way old-timers test file existence?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071023-00/?p=24713) But since you've probably solved the wrong problem altogether, read this, too: [You just have to accept that the file system can change](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071109-00/?p=24553).

Comment: The problem is the system is trying to resolve  the network connection, and waits for tcp replies a long time. And suspends the thread that is related until there is an answer.         I believe my problem is solvable by adjusting somehow the tcp timeout of networking. But then it will effect the whole system and it may cause other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the fast variant

add a module with the following code:

```
#If VBA7 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, lpExitCode As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hHandle As Long, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FormatMessage Lib "kernel32" Alias "FormatMessageA" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, lpSource As Any, ByVal dwMessageId As Long, ByVal dwLanguageId As Long, ByVal lpBuffer As String, ByVal nSize As Long, Arguments As Long) As Long

#Else
Private Declare Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, lpExitCode As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hHandle As Long, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function FormatMessage Lib "kernel32" Alias "FormatMessageA" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, lpSource As Any, ByVal dwMessageId As Long, ByVal dwLanguageId As Long, ByVal lpBuffer As String, ByVal nSize As Long, Arguments As Long) As Long

#End If

Public Const INFINITE = &HFFFF
Public Const PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = &H1F0FFF
public Const SYNCHRONIZE = &H100000


Sub test()
 If FileExistsFast("c:\Windows\win.ini") Then
  MsgBox "exists"
 Else
  MsgBox "not"
 End If
End Sub

Sub test_hard()
 Dim file
 file = "\\random" & Mid(Str(Rnd()), 3, 5) & "\Windows\win.ini"
 'msgbox file
 If FileExistsFast(file) Then
  MsgBox "exists"
 Else
  MsgBox "not"
 End If
End Sub

Public Function FileExistsFast(file)
    FileExistsFast = False
    Dim Cmd As String
    Cmd = "cmd /c dir """ & file & """"
    lTaskID = Shell(Cmd, 0)
    ' Get process handle

    ' lPID = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, True, lTaskID)
    lPID = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, True, lTaskID) ' suggested by a comment from IInspectable not sure if it works, should work
    If lPID Then
        'Wait for process to finish
        Dim result As Integer

        result = WaitForSingleObject(lPID, 1000) ' set tiemout for 1000 ms
        If result > 240 Then ' 258 process not closed yet , 259 status of process is not closed
               'MsgBox "not returned "
        Else
            'Get Exit Process
            If GetExitCodeProcess(lPID, lexitcode) Then
                'Received value
                'MsgBox "Successfully returned " & lExitCode, vbInformation
                If lexitcode = 0 Then
                    FileExistsFast = True
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox "Failed: " & DLLErrorText(Err.LastDllError), vbCritical
            End If
        End If
        lTaskID = CloseHandle(lPID)
    Else
        lTaskID = 0
        MsgBox "Failed: " & DLLErrorText(Err.LastDllError), vbCritical
    End If
End Function



Public Function DLLErrorText(ByVal lLastDLLError As Long) As String
    Dim sBuff As String * 256
    Dim lCount As Long
    Const FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER = &H100, FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY = &H2000
    Const FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE = &H800, FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_STRING = &H400
    Const FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM = &H1000, FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS = &H200
    Const FORMAT_MESSAGE_MAX_WIDTH_MASK = &HFF

    lCount = FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM Or FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, 0, lLastDLLError, 0&, sBuff, Len(sBuff), ByVal 0)
    If lCount Then
        DLLErrorText = Left$(sBuff, lCount - 2) \\Remove line feeds
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: If all you need is to synchronize with a process object, use `SYNCHRONIZE`. You don't need `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` for that. In fact, it's rare that you *ever* need `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS`.

Comment: And there certainly has to be an API you can call directly to do the same work, without resorting to shelling out to `cmd.exe`

Comment: @Remy Lebeau. I did not found. The api is slow. I am sure there is a c++ api. But I can't have it from Access.

Comment: Did the solution works for you? please feel free to mark yourself.

Comment: for me? yes, it works well. now it does not freeze when checking if a file in a network share exists when the server is not available

Comment: I did not have a change to check the SYNCHRONIZE  yet